# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in boot due to failed x11vnc service

Tags: boot, 22.04, vnc

I'll preface this by mentioning that I'm currently learning Ubuntu and definitely not an experienced user. Now I've encountered this problem that, out of the blue, my Ubuntu 22.04 system is not able to boot anymore and gets stuck in "[Failed] Failed to start x11vnc service".

I have tried booting it from a removable disk, that works just fine. I have also tried entering the advanced options in the bootloader and executing some of the repair options there (dpkg, grub). If I then continue boot in this recovery mode, everything seems to work just fine. However, upon rebooting in regular mode, I again receive the x11vnc error and my boot gets stuck.

Now my question is: why does my system revert to the x11vnc problem after the repair in recovery mode? Is there anything else I'm missing? How would I go about fixing this?

If you need any additional information, please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK x11vnc is not a core service (in fact I don't think the Ubuntu x11vnc package even installs service files - this must be something you or the system's administrator have configured). So perhaps something else is causing the issue, and the x11vnc error just happens to be the last thing that's printed before normal boot hangs? Anyhow you could consider disabling / masking the x11vnc service in the meantime.

Comment: @steeldriver I completely removed x11vnc, but I'm still getting the same error. Also looked into the system journal to see if there's any other major failure before it prints the x11vnc error, but I couldn't find any significant problems. Starting to think a clean reinstall might be the only solution..

Comment: If you just removed the Ubuntu `x11vnc` package, you may still have a manually configured service file - something like `sudo systemctl mask x11vnc.service` was more what I had in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found out that the current kernel appears to be faulty. Tried a few older and newer kernels and these all boot perfectly fine. As steeldriver suggested, the x11vnc error indeed appears to be unrelated. Closing this for now.